# MacOS Reclaim free space on Disk for APFS container after deleting APFS Container

Tags: hard-drive, big-sur, apfs, space

I have an 8 TB disk in my Mac. I had 2 APFS containers on it (`disk7` and `disk8`). After deleting APFS container `disk8`, I get this:

[image]

The space that the deleted APFS container `disk 8` used up is lost and not reclaimed by APFS container `disk 7`.

I tried  `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk5s1 0`, but no result. I can only use 4.3 TB of my 8 TB disk.

How can I make container `disk 7` use all 8 TB?

sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk5
[image]

Comment: Can you give the result of command ```sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk5```?

Comment: I added a picture to the question with the sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk5 result

Comment: Which leaves my question still unanswered:

How can I make container disk 7 use all 8 TB?

Comment: Your free space is before the actual apfs struture. Can you create a Big Sur USB key and boot on? This will permit create an apfs structure on the free space. Then you reboot on your internal system and if necessary you will clone the apfs structure of disk7 on the new structure created before and then you can suppress the container disk7 and after add the free space to the new structure apfs. Carbon copy Cloner can help you for create the clone.

Comment: Basically, this is a duplicate question. The question [How do i regain all my storage? I was running linux mint on MacBook Pro and have now gone back to Mac OS big sur and only have half the storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421980/how-do-i-regain-all-my-storage-i-was-running-linux-mint-on-macbook-pro-and-have) involves having free space before the APFS container. Any answer to the other question would probably also answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. 
I cloned all Data from the disk to another disk.
Then I reformated the whole disk and copied the data back to its original disk.
It took about 3-4 days of nostop Carbon Copy Cloner.
This is the year 2021. This is MacOS by Apple. What a disaster. What a piece of Cr*p.

Comment: Kentsay: The other question include the output from `diskutil list`. This showed there was enough free space to support cloning. In your case, you supplied the output from `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk5` which does not provide this information. This is why I stated answers to the other question would probably work in your case, but I can not be certain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.
After several days of unsuccessful searching for a solution that allows to free up the unused space on the Disk and make it available for storage I gave up and:
I cloned all Data from the disk to another disk. Then I reformated the whole disk and copied the data back to its original disk. It took about 3-4 days of nonstop Carbon Copy Cloner. This is the year 2021. This is MacOS Big Sur by Apple. What a disaster. What a piece of Cr*p.

Comment: Windows, Linux and macOS all do not have a built-in way to expand a partition upward. So there is nothing special about Big Sur in this regard.